# remove first number(s) followed by a ";" and remove then also the rest of ";" but keep the followed numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

trying (still 2 days) to figure out how i can remove the first number(s), followes by an `";"` and leave the rest of numbers but remove still all `";"` and replace them with an tab `("\t")`. 
The base numbers (loaded by script from one .txt file):

```
1;999.99;999.99;-999.99  <-- should be  999.99  999.99  -999.99 --><br />
2;248.22;257.78;-10.58   <-- should be  248.22  257.78  -10.58 --><br />
3;235.54;149.58;-14.32   <-- should be  235.54  149.58  -14.32 --><br />
10;225.54;147.58;-14.32  <-- should be  225.54  147.58  -14.32 --><br />
```

the List goes up to 99;
i tried

```
replace(/.*;(?! \.d+;)/g, "\t");
```

but this will remove all ";" and numbers, except the last numbers.
I can't figure i out. who can help?

my complete code tryed with the answer from  `"hex494D49"`:

> ```
>     function readTheNpFile01() {
>       var initNpFile = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
>       projektname = projektname_input.value;
>       openNP01 = initNpFile.OpenTextFile("C://wamp/www/CM5_demo/cnc_temp/" + projektname + ".cnc.01np", 1, false); 
>       readALLofNP01 = openNP01.ReadAll().replace(/0;0.0;0.0;0.0/i, "");//.slice(7);
>       for(i = 0; i < readALLofNP01.length; i++){
>         console.log(readALLofNP01[i].replace(/(^\d+;)|;/g, '\t'));
>       }
>       $('#NP01row').html(readALLofNP01); //put the numbers in my html ID
>       openNP01.Close(); 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer doing it with RegEx, here's a solution

```
'1;999.99;999.99;-999.99'.replace(/(^\d+;)|;/g, '\t');
```

If you don't want `\t` at the beginning, trim the output

```
'1;999.99;999.99;-999.99'.replace(/(^\d+;)|;/g, '\t').trim();
```

If the input is a text file then use the snippet below

```
var text = "here is the content of the file";
// strip text file in lines 
var lines = text.match(/[^\r\n]+/g); // or var lines = text.split("\n");
for(i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
    // do the nedeed changes
    console.log(lines[i].replace(/(^\d+;)|;/g, '\t').trim());
}
```

Check the working [jsFiddle](http://jsbin.com/defakexe/1/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: It will add `\t` in the beginning as well.

Comment: @ hex494d49 yes, like this it is working. but i'am getting the numners by a text file and it is like: 
1;999.99;999.99;-999.99 <br/>

2;248.22;257.78;-10.58 < br /> 
3;235.54;149.58;-14.32 < br /> 
10;225.54;147.58;-14.32 < br />...

i tryed to use your code, but it is not working. ee my complete code in my qustion on top.......:

Comment: @user3825577 Check the updated answer; I added the code to slip text in lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
var n = "1;999.99;999.99;-999.99";

n = n.slice(n.indexOf(';')+1).replace(/;/g, "\t");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bVz5K/3/)

Comment: `n.length` is redundant - omitting the second parameter to `.slice` will imply getting the rest of the string. But +1 for doing the right thing and breaking the two steps into two steps rather than trying to do it all at once with a regex.

Comment: Hi ADENEO, thanks at first! 
>This works, but only for the first numbers... now n all numbers the ";" is gone, but the first two numbers are still there (only first numbers "999.99 999.99 -999.99" are perfekt.

Comment: @user3825577 - I only tried it with the first number, but trying the rest seems to work for me as well -> **http://jsfiddle.net/bVz5K/4/**

Comment: one by one ist also working für me, but i've all Numbers at the same time, and then it os not working..

Comment: Well of course it doesn't, split the numbers and do them one by one.

Answer (score -1):

thank you all for your help. at the end, al your answers helped me to find the solution.
here the CODE. (THANKS AGAIN)

```
      openNP01 = initNpFile.OpenTextFile("C://wamp/www/CM5_demo/cnc_temp/" + projektname + ".cnc.01np", 1, false);
  readALLofNP01 = openNP01.ReadAll().replace(/0;0.0;0.0;0.0/i, "").slice(7);
  NP01Array = readALLofNP01.replace(/(^\d{1,2};)|;/gm, '\t').trim();
  $('#NP01row').html(NP01Array); 
openNP01.Close();
```